# Trigger a function when condition in ngIf turns true in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there a way in which I can trigger a function just after the ngIf condition turns true and the DOM is rendered accordingly?

Condition: the click and the ngif are applied to different blocks

Comment: Can you display some example code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a getter/setter on the `trigger` property.

With the following code, the `<div>` is rendered AND the `doSomething()` method gets executed as soon as you do `this.trigger = true`:

```ts
@Component({
  template: `<div *ngIf="trigger">I've been triggered</div>`
})
export class MyComp {
  private _trigger = false;

  get trigger() {
    return this._trigger;
  }

  set trigger(val) {
    this._trigger = val;
    this.doSomething();  // Call some method
  }

  doSomething() {
    // ...
  }
}
```